# idProperty in Sencha Touch 2.3.1

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, getter

I have the model:

```
 Ext.define('EvaluateIt.model.Address', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        idProperty: 'id', 
        fields: [
            {name: 'address', type: 'string'},
            {name: 'city', type: 'string'},
            {name: 'state', type: 'string'},
            {name: 'zipcode', type: 'string'},
            {name: 'county', type: 'string'}
        ],
        proxy: {
            type: "sql", 
            database: 'Test'
        }

    }
});
```

In my controller, I insert data into this model as follows:

```
 var address = Ext.create('EvaluateIt.model.Address', {
     address: json[i].garden.address.address
  });
 address.save();
```

Where the json array is grabbed via Ajax and thus inserted into the model without any problems.

However, when I try to access the id from the model like,

```
console.log('address.id ' + address.id);
```

I get something of the form ext-record-n (where n does not even map to the id in my Address table). How can I reference the actual value of the id column in this table? I tried this, but was unsuccessful: https://github.com/tomalex0/SenchaTouch-v2-SqliteProxy/issues/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the id field to the fields array will cause the proxy to create the database table with column id as an AUTOINCREMENT field.

```
Ext.define('EvaluateIt.model.Address', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        idProperty: 'id', 
        fields: [
            {name: 'id', type: 'int'},
            {name: 'address', type: 'string'},
            {name: 'city', type: 'string'},
            {name: 'state', type: 'string'},
            {name: 'zipcode', type: 'string'},
            {name: 'county', type: 'string'}
        ],
        proxy: {
            type: "sql", 
            database: 'Test'
        }

    }
});
```

The proxy will read the id value created by the database. You can access the value by passing a callback function to the model save method.

```
var address = Ext.create('EvaluateIt.model.Address', {
     address: json[i].garden.address.address
});

address.save(function(record) {
    console.log('address.id ' + record.getId();
}, this);
```

Comment: I just tried this Jeff, but it is exhibiting the same behavior. Here is a sample of the output: address id is ext-record-24 ... Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, it works a bit differently when working with the model directly instead of using a store. I edited my answer to get the id value in a callback function passed to the save method.

Comment: Sweet! Worked like a charm. Now that you mention it, I was going to try using a store, but I needed access to the model's associations. Thanks again!